# Invoking intent from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a fragment

```
public class TwitterFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {}
```

From this fragment I am invoking an intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
```

where,

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
```

But Invoking intent is giving error:

```
Error:(214, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(TwitterFragment,Class<WebViewActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; TwitterFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; TwitterFragment cannot be converted to Context)
```

This code was working when TwitterFragment class extends Activity instead of fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fragment` is not a `Context`. Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Intent demands a `Context` as its first parameter. Do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourTargetClass.class);
```

And to actually *start* your `Activity`, do this:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

`Fragment` doesn't extend `Context`, so it borrows it from its housing `Activity`. That is why you can't get your `Intent` working the first time you try it.

Comment: I can't believe this xD

Answer (score 1):

Get the activity for the context parameter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity() instead of this.
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);