# android.content.Context.getPackageName() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am getting this error when transtioning from a fragment to an activity as shown below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference         at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)         at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6108)
```

Below is my code for going to the next activity, The error occurs on the first line of the code below.

```
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent (getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            mainIntent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity (mainIntent);
```

I don't see any solution so far online.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419916/2711811 when creating `Intent`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're getting a wrong context that raises this `NullPointerException`

Try to replace the below line:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent (getContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

With: >> if you're within an activity

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
```

with: >> if you're within a callback listener within the activity

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent (MyActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

With: >> if you're within a fragment

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent (requireActivity(), MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with getActivity() intsead of getContext()

Answer (score 1):

I work the transaction of the fragment with this code

```
private Context context;

context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to find a work around this. I realised I am getting the error because I am creating the new Intent inside the firebase OnCompleteListener as shown below. So after i removed it from inside the listener and called it outside, my program works properly.

I instead created a global boolean variable that I updated to true on successful data storage. Then I can access it somewhere else and then transtion to another if true.

```
 #BEFORE

    PostsRef.child(key).updateChildren(postsMap)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New Post is updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent (getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                                mainIntent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                startActivity (mainIntent);
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured while updating your post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
#AFTER

 PostsRef.child(key).updateChildren(postsMap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        mSuccess = true;
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New Post is updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured while updating your post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys I have also realised one of the big causes of this error is the lifecycle methods.So I was overriding them inside my fragment to update the user state on the firebase database. Because of this they caused the `android.content.Context.getPackageName() on a null object reference` error whenever I tried to move to the main activity managing it. Incase I used the fragment transition to move to another fragment, the MainActivity would get excecuted more than twice. After stopping to override them my application worked properly. **If someone would explain why that happens it would be great.**

```
   @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
    updateUserState("Online");
        }
@Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    updateUserState("Online");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are calling from a ***Fragment***, you should use **getActivity()** here instead of getContext()

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent (getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity (mainIntent);
```

This should help I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes startActivity method throws an exception like:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
> the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

So you should `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` method